# Issues with converting a Python GUI Controller file to a EXE (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I have a python controller GUI file (with an MVC architecture). The file is calling other files (model.py and view.py), and tkinter to generate plots and data. I also have two class .py (one reads a complex csv and other creates a dictionary). I have kept all these files in one directory. I am using Python 3.6 (though have used Python 3.5 for testing too, which did not work). ( I am using pandas, tkinter)

I have run the controller.py file separately and have seen it is giving the desired output.

To convert to .exe I have tried py2exe, cx_Freeze and Pyinstaller and nothing works. With Python 3.5 and cx_Freeze, I am getting the .exefile, but after double click it kills iteself in 5 secs.

For Pyinstaller either I got JSOn issue ( which I fixed via PyQt5 clean install) and now getting maximum recursion depth exceeded.

So not understanding my way out.

The way I am running the pyinstaller is: (from the directory where all the files are)

pyinstaller -wF controller.py

Am I doing correctly, given that controller.py is calling other python files and packages?